# How can we value NPV for a standard FX Swap?

Tags: fx, swaps, forward, spot-rate

hope you are all well!

Was just wondering how we can value the NPV on the value date for a FX swap - i'm sure it's by evaluating the interest rate payable/receivable from the trade date until the value date?

for the short term swaps i.e - SN, TN, ON - how can we calculate what the end NPV is from trade date > value date?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

(I will use the quotation FOR/DOM for any currency pair)

As you know, an FX swap consists in two transactions :

- A purchase (or sale) of a currency FOR at a specific date (often, but not always, the spot date of the currency pair. If spot : fx swap = spot + forward // If not spot : fx swap = forward + forward).
- An opposite transaction : a sale (or purchase) of the currency FOR at a later date.

The amount can be the same (Even swap) or different (uneven swap). The dates can match the classic tenors (ON, TN, SN, SW (=1W), 2W, 1M, etc...).

You also know that the value of an FX swap is zero at inception.

Globally, what you should remember is that only the forward leg(s) matter for the evaluation of the fx swap.

If it's a spot + forward, you can value the NPV only by considering the forward leg.
If it is a forward + forward, can can compute both NPV and add up together to get your swap NPV.

Indeed, once the spot transaction is done, what matters is only the forward leg (implicitly your interest rate differential, your points).

Value of a forward in a FOR notional :

[image]

Compute this formula for any forward legs and you're good to go :)

Comment: Related question https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/38908/valuation-of-an-fx-swap